# Dynamic window creation at runtime using ncurses

Tags: dynamic, window, ncurses, creation

Not sure if this is even possible with ncurses. All documentation and examples show that the creation of multiple windows is known at compile time.
I would like to do something like this.

```
 #include <ncurses.h>

WINDOW *create_newwin(int height, int width, int starty, int startx);
void star(int x,int y,int r);
 void newbox(int x,int y,int r);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{       
    int startx, starty, width, height;
    int ch,sze;

    initscr();                      /* Start curses mode            */
    cbreak();                       /* Line buffering disabled, Pass on
                                     * everty thing to me           */
    //printf("%s\n",argv[1]);
    sze = atoi(argv[1]);
    starty = (LINES - sze) / 2;  /* Calculating for a center placement */
    startx = (COLS - sze) / 2;    /* of the window                */

    refresh();
    star(startx,starty,sze);

    endwin();                       /* End curses mode                */
    return 0;
}

WINDOW *create_newwin(int height, int width, int starty, int startx)
{       WINDOW *local_win;

    local_win = newwin(height, width, starty, startx);
    box(local_win, 0 , 0);          /* 0, 0 gives default characters
                                     * for the vertical and horizontal
                                     * lines                        */
    wrefresh(local_win);            /* Show that box                */

    return local_win;
}


void star(int x,int y,int r)
{
if(r>0)
{
star(x-r,y+r,r/2);
star(x+r,y+r,r/2);
star(x-r,y-r,r/2);
star(x+r,y-r,r/2);
 newbox(x,y,r);
 }
}

void newbox(int x,int y,int r)
 {
  WINDOW *mywin;
   mywin = create_newwin(2*r, 2*r, y, x);
 }
```

I would think that you would use the new keyword and malloc. My desired goal is to produce a type of fractal display with overlapping windows.The function star is a recursive one that will create the parameters to pass to the newbox function. Anyone out there used ncurses to create windows at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (n)curses function [`newwin`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_window.3x.html) allocates space for a `WINDOW` structure and returns that.  The `stdscr` and `curscr` windows likewise are *allocated* in [`initscr`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html) or `newterm` (using `newwin`).  The main difference between `stdscr` and `curscr` versus other windows is that these are used throughout the library in a predefined manner, and cannot be freed.  The other windows can be freed using [`delwin`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_window.3x.html).  None of that is "static".

The corresponding manual pages have this basic information.

The ncurses [example programs](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-examples.html) show how windows can be created which are not explicit in the code, e.g., prompting for the user to move the cursor to begin creating a window, then moving to select the end (top-left versus bottom-right, in menu item `g` below).  Likewise, several use recursion, e.g., to draw a series of nested, boxed windows (menu item `a` or `A` below, used to test [`resizeterm`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/resizeterm.3x.html)).  Those are both done in the main test-program, whose menu is shown here:

```
Welcome to ncurses 5.9.20150502.  Press ? for help.
This is the ncurses main menu
a = keyboard and mouse input test
A = wide-character keyboard and mouse input test
b = character attribute test
B = wide-character attribute test
c = color test pattern
C = color test pattern using wide-character calls
d = edit RGB color values
e = exercise soft keys
E = exercise soft keys using wide-characters
f = display ACS characters
F = display Wide-ACS characters
g = display windows and scrolling
i = test of flushinp()
k = display character attributes
m = menu code test
o = exercise panels library
O = exercise panels with wide-characters
p = exercise pad features
q = quit
r = exercise forms code
s = overlapping-refresh test
t = set trace level
? = repeat this command summary
>
```

Comment: Just one more question. I tried to use run : " make -f Makfile.in " but it gave an error of  " Makefile.in:40: *** missing separator.  Stop. " any suggestions?

Comment: You have to use the `configure` script to create the appropriate `Makefile`, e.g., "`./configure && make`"

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks again. Could you put that instruction in the README for us newbies?

Comment: I will do that (on my to-do list).